# Add header value to query string

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an interesting situation where I have a apache module adding a header to the incoming request. The backend application also need this header to be added to the query string. For example.

The header added is

```
company=exampleco
```

For a incoming query string

```
http://www.example.com/
```

.. the query string does then need to be set to

```
http://www.example.com/?company=exampleco
```

Any idea if it is possible to add headers added by a module to the query string?

Comment: Are you using a ProxyPass or mod_rewrite rules to forward the request to the backend application or some other mechanism? But in mod_rewrite you can use the value of the header `company` with `%{HTTP:company}`

Comment: Right now Im using ProxyPass, but cant we add a mod_rewrite aswell?

Comment: Another thing how can we know that the module adding the header is exceuted before the mod_rewrite

Comment: You know by testing :) - And ProxyPass rules can also be implemented in RewriteRules with the `[P]` flag